# $N = 11+22+33+……….100100$ . If $N$ is divided by $16$, then what is the remainder?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

I tried to find a pattern in the remainder when each term is divided by $16$, but I was not able to recognize any pattern.
The remainder I get when I divide each term by $16$ is as follows :- 
$11,6,1,3,7,1,13,1,3,1,7,3,.......$ and I do not see a pattern here.

So I was thinking that I will be able to get a pattern and then I will sum up the values in the repeating pattern and then multiply it by the number of times it will repeat and proceed from there but it doesn't seem to work in this problem. Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: You can see the sum as $11 \sum_{i=1}^{100} i$.

Comment: Please clarify the term after $99$.  If it is $1010$ then this is not divisible by $11$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
N&=11+22+\dots 100100\\
&=11\times (1+2+\dots 9100)\\
&=11\times \frac{9100\times 9101}{2}\\
&=11\times 4550\times 9101
\end{align*}
Now, look at the individual remainders of the three numbers on division by $16$ and multiply them.

Comment: Ok! I totally missed this idea. Great! Thanks, A lot !!! This makes this problem super simple.

Comment: Depending on what happens after $99$, I don't think this works. If the next term is $1010$ then it is not divisible by $11$.  The OP should clarify but my interpretation would be that there are $100$ terms in the sequence not $9100$.  The idea is good but I think that you need to split it into parts and handle each part separately.

Comment: @badjohn your concern is quite interesting! I didn't think about that possible version when I solved it. But, honestly, if I was setting this question and I meant your version, I would have written something more like $N = 11+22+33+\dots 99+1010+1111+\dots +100100$. Anyways, if the OP clarifies this doubt, I'll change my answer accordingly (by splitting it into parts as you mentioned).